# Wordpress does not detect all images in uploads folder?

Tags: media-library, customization

I have about 500,000 images in the /uploads folder, but in Wordpress admin the media library only shows 10,000 images used (which is correct) and 10,000 unattached. In reality it's more like 490,000 unattached. I sshd and can confirm that the files are indeed there, Wordpress is just not showing them. They are normal jpg images, nothing unusual about them. Permissions on the images are 777.

I'd like it to show all images so I can go through them month by month and delete all the unused images. I know there are plugins for deleting unused images but none of them worked for me, so I have no choice but to do it manually.

The images used to have posts attached to them but those posts were deleted a long time ago and the images remained.

How can I make Wordpress detect all images in the /uploads folder?

Thanks!

Comment: WordPress doesn't "detect" images in the uploads folder, it only knows of the images that have attachment data in the database. You can try the [add from server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/) plugin to import them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Add from server doesn't seem to paginate, and it would be a big hassle to import half a million files. What do you think would be the best way to do this: Delete all images in /uploads folder except those that exist in the Wordpress database?